# C# Certificado Digital A3 CPF Token

Tags: c#, certificado-digital

Eu tenho que colocar um certificado digital do tipo CPF A3 token com senha, num HttpWebRequest, para isso estava tentando usar o X509Certificate2, da seguinte forma:

```
    private X509Certificate2 GetCert(string CertFile, string CertPass)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(CertFile, FileMode.Open);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(buffer, CertPass);
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
        return cert;
    }

    //chamo assim
    GetCert("C:\\certificado.cer", password);
```

Mas me informaram que isso era para ler certificados no meu computador, então tentei o codigo abaixo

```
        X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        //my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);


        // Find the certificate we'll use to sign            
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in my.Certificates)
        {
            var x509 = cert;
            byte[] rawData = x509.RawData;
            Console.WriteLine("Content Type: {0}", X509Certificate2.GetCertContentType(rawData));
            Console.WriteLine("Serial Number: {0}", x509.SerialNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Friendly Name: {0}", x509.FriendlyName);
            //continue
```

Só que esse código esta funcionando OK só para certificados de CNPJ, quando uso CPF ele pede para que eu espete um pen drive com certificado... Mais uma coisa estranha é: ele esta lendo todos os certificados que um dia eu já instalei no computador...

Comment: Creio que o certificado exportado de um *Smart Card* ou de um pendrive não possui a chave privada. O certo seria ler do USB mesmo.

Comment: Estou meio perdido entre chave privada e senha... Eu sei que preciso alem de espetar o pen drive, colocar uma senha para usar ele no chrome por exemplo...

Comment: Diego, ele pega todos os certificados mesmo, temos vários deles instalados, você pode verificá-los através no IE. No caso do CPF ele deve pedir o pendrive porque lá está o certificado, não é?

Comment: De fato, eu entendi melhor isso tudo, agora só estou tendo problemas em como por a senha no certificado.... O que é a ordem a fazer? Como adiciono a senha no certificado?

Comment: Não testei o código, mas este cara diz que conseguiu adicionar o PIN automaticamente.
https://helpdev.com.br/2017/08/11/como-adicionar-pinsenha-automaticamente-no-certificado-a3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o certificado A3 oferece uma proteção extra, já que a chave privada fica inacessível a não ser pelo hardware (Smart Card). Não tem como exportá-la. O que você exporta é apenas a chave pública.
Quanto à senha, ela só possibilita o acesso à chave primária dentro do Smart Card, isso porque a senha que você digita criptografa/descriptografa a chave primária como incremento de segurança.
Algumas referências:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774469/how-does-the-rsa-private-key-passphrase-work-under-the-hood;
- https://martin.kleppmann.com/2013/05/24/improving-security-of-ssh-private-keys.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5FEqGYLL0o

Comment: Muito bom para entendimento do certificado A3, Obrigado. Mas não explica muito como fazer ou oque esta errado no meu código..

Comment: Pelo que eu vi no seu código você está tratando o A3 como um arquivo, mas ele é um cartão, para abri-lo você tem que acessar o "repositório" de certificados, no C# tem uma classe que faz isso é a "X509Store" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store(v=vs.110).aspx) e tem também a X509Certificate2Collection (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find(v=vs.110).aspx), espero que tenha ajudado

Comment: OK, vou ver, ajudou sim, obrigado

Comment: Então funciona legal isso aqui Só que só para CNPJ, alterei o codigo acima

Comment: @diegocolli vc conseguiu resolver a questão do PIN que o token A3 pede? Como colocar ele via código e inibir a exibição da tela que pede o PIN?

Comment: Eu dei um jeito, mas não lembro direito. Eu acho que tinha algum problema na minha configuração ou classes que estava usando, porque se me lembro bem foi só fazer direito que nem abria essa janela, infelizmente não tenho mais acesso ao código para dar mais info...